# Hadoop job just ends

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm having a rather strange problem with Hadoop.

I wrote a MR job that ends just like that, without executing map or reduce code. It produces the output folder, but that folder is empty. I see no reason for such a behavior.

I'm even trying out this with default Mapper and Reducer, just to find the problem, but I get no exception, no error, the job just finishes and produces an empty folder. Here's the simplest driver:

```
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    //DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI(firstPivotsInput), conf);

    Job pivotSelection = new Job(conf);
    pivotSelection.setJarByClass(Driver.class);
    pivotSelection.setJobName("Silhoutte");

    pivotSelection.setMapperClass(Mapper.class);
    pivotSelection.setReducerClass(Reducer.class);

    pivotSelection.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
    pivotSelection.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    pivotSelection.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
    pivotSelection.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(pivotSelection, new Path("/home/pera/WORK/DECOMPRESSION_RESULT.csv"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(pivotSelection, new Path("/home/pera/WORK/output"));

    pivotSelection.setNumReduceTasks(1);

    pivotSelection.waitForCompletion(true);
```

What could be the problem in such a simple example?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest explanation is that the input Path (`"/home/pera/WORK/DECOMPRESSION_RESULT.csv"`) does not contain anything **on HDFS**. You can verify that by the value of the MAP_INPUT_RECORDS counter. You can also check the size of this file on HDFS with `hadoop dfs -ls /home/pera/WORK`, or you can even see the first few lines of this file by `hadoop dfs -cat /home/pera/WORK/DECOMPRESSION_RESULT.csv | head`. (or `-text` instead of `-cat` if it is compressed).

Another problem could be that the reducer has a special (if) condition that fails for every mapper's output, but this should not hold in the case of identity mapper and reducer, so I believe the case is the former one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it does have entries and it's on local file system, I'm running it in standalone mode, through IDE? Also, when I  try a custom mapper and set a breakpoint in setup method same happens. Like I haven't set the mapper..

Comment: @pera but it should still be on HDFS. try putting it there and see if it runs